# How to notice any change on a form

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls

I have a form with many different radiobuttons, checkboxes and textboxes. Depending on their values I start my calculations. The results are shown on the same form and panel. If any of my controls (checkboxes, ...) changes, I want to immediatly update the results without a need to press any update-button.
I could define a statsChanged-sub for every single control on the form but there are so many. Isn't there a way/event of the form starting whenever a control is changed? It should be something like controlOnFormChanged. How can I get a sub that starts whenever a any control on the form changed?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wire up the events that correspond to the desired change manually to a specific event handler:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Iterate through all controls and handle them according to their type
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (c) Is CheckBox Then
                AddHandler CType(c, CheckBox).CheckedChanged, AddressOf SomethingChanged
            ElseIf TypeOf (c) Is RadioButton Then
                AddHandler CType(c, RadioButton).CheckedChanged, AddressOf SomethingChanged
            ElseIf TypeOf (c) Is TextBox Then
                AddHandler CType(c, TextBox).TextChanged, AddressOf SomethingChanged
            ElseIf ......
                ......
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomethingChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Whatever it is you do
    End Sub
End Class
```

Whenever one of the events on a control fires the sub SomethingChanged is called, allowing you to update your results.

Please be aware: If you have controls in subcontainers like `Panels` you need to modify this method and iteratively get all controls in all containers.

Here is, for example, a solution to this:

http://kon-phum.com/tutors/pascal/programming_cs_getcontrolsonform.html

```
Public Shared Function GetAllControls(ctrls As IList) As List(Of Control)
    Dim RetCtrls As New List(Of Control)()
    For Each ctl As Control In ctrls
        RetCtrls.Add(ctl)
        Dim SubCtrls As List(Of Control) = GetAllControls(ctl.Controls)
        RetCtrls.AddRange(SubCtrls)
    Next
    Return RetCtrls
End Function
```

Comment: I changed the TextBox-Handler to .Leave, so my calculations don't start with every key but after I leave the TextBox. Works perfectly for me, thank you!